# ME3 Helmet is OFF all the time despite menu setting 'default'. Am I missing something?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I want helmet on during combat missions

Answer (score 3):

The Default setting keeps the helmet off in atmospheric environments and on during non-atmospheric or dangerous environments. I would recommend setting the menu option to "Always On." This will keep the helmet on during gameplay except during cutscenes (this cannot be changed without editing the save file).